# MailChimp template add script tag at the end of html template

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

I used email template creator MailChimp, I figure out at the end of html body there is a script with type 'text/javascript' that src is not clear for me and I can't find any reason for that, for example

`<script type="text/javascript"  src="/thukjgfg/iOt1cffw/S20SQQE/PBY/PeloHEXkB"></script>`

is anybody know what is it?

Answer (score 2):

You have created a template in the standard template builder.
After creation, you exported the html code. After the export, there is indeed a script tag. If you create a campaign and send template then there will be no script tag.

Conclusion: Most likely, the script tag is tied to the template builder settings.

Comment: maybe its, I tried to remove the tag and i did upload again to MailChimp, and then download template, the script was gone, and i test  it and there was no problem and mail succeed sent.